# creating a Factory class with SharePoint server side API to instantiate a wrapper class around SPWeb?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, factory-pattern

Has anyone ever got the idea of creating a Factory class with SharePoint server side API to instantiate a wrapper class around SPWeb?

I mean, for site created with different templates, or same template with different features turned on, I want to define different C# classes, so that i can associate different methods with it, and i can leverage all those C# OO features such as inheritance.

As far as i know, a lot of SharePoint classes are either sealed or have internal constructors.

And if i want to bind a SPWeb with something such as a Managed Metadata Navigation Term or non SharePoint type, it might be better to use a wrapper instead of inherit from SharePoint class.

Answer (score 0):

your question is already quiet old, but I came across your idea (looking to implement something similar) and wanted to let you (and everyone reading this) know that for configuration for like Managed Metadata and setting up and environment there is SPMeta2.

It's an open source, free to use framework which allows you to define and configure your SharePoint.

Regarding your other goals, have you implemented something like that, could you be more specific?